# Sending commands to a set of session

Tags: windows, ssh, telnet

In SecureCRT there is an option to send one command to all opened sessions (mainly for telnet/ssh connections).
Does somebody familiar with some free program which can run on Windows that can do the same?

BR

Answer (score 1):

I use MobaXterm for exactly that :-)

http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/

Comment: But this is limited for 12 sessions to be saved (unless it is purchased)

Comment: Yes...how many do you need? They have to feed their children too you know, and it ain't expensive!